# Can a warlock with Devil's Sight see through Fog Cloud?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Basically what is written in the title. How does Devil's sight work with heavily obscured areas different to natural darkness and the spell Darkness?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to see through smoke as opposed to "darkness"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72780/is-there-a-way-to-see-through-smoke-as-opposed-to-darkness)

Comment: Related: [Interaction between fog cloud and new vision errata rule](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122315)

Comment: @TJL I think it's related, but not a dupe.  (Good catch on the previous Q&A on the obscured by smoke ...)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I can see that... or not see, as the case may be. ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### No.

The ability does what it says:

> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical...

Darkness is the lack of light. Smoke and fog aren't "darkness" any more than a blindfold is.