# Can someone with Devil's Sight see inside a Fog Cloud spell while a sphere of Darkness remains at the centre of the fog?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, vision-and-light, special-senses

Basically, in a session, we had the party come up against a group of Bugbears who attacked the party in an ambush. In a moment of haste, the party's warlock cast Fog Cloud to help obscure against the bugbears to try and cause an even ground for the fight. At the same time, to give their team an edge, the Warlock cast Darkness on one of their allies' blades so that they could see within the darkness and give at least two of the members who had Devil's Sight advantage in the fight.

If someone casts Fog Cloud and then another person casts Darkness within the area of fog, does the darkness basically remove any trace of the fog within, even for those with Devil's Sight? Or do those with Devil's Sight see nothing but the fog within the darkness?

I would like some clarification as to know in the future how to react to this, should the tactic be reused.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Can a warlock with Devil's Sight see through Fog Cloud?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126040/33569), [Is there a way to see through smoke as opposed to “darkness”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72780/33569), [Does the spell Fog Cloud obscure light sources?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137103/33569)

Comment: Also, if the *darkness* spell is specifically at the center of the area of the *fog cloud* spell, does that mean that there is fog on all sides of the area of magical darkness? Or do you just mean the spells' areas overlap? (Even at 1st level, the area of *fog cloud* is larger than that of *darkness*.)

Comment: How is the Warlock maintaining concentration on both *Fog Cloud* and *Darkness*? Or are there two Warlocks?

Comment: @RevanantBacon "If someone casts Fog Cloud and then another person casts Darkness"

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I saw "The party's warlock casts *Fog Cloud*" which implies that there is in fact, *one* warlock, which was followed by "the warlock casts *Darkness*", which implies that it was the same warlock casting both spells. Which, of course, led to my request for clarification on how this situation even came up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You would see only fog**

The rules for heavily obscured areas reads as follows:

> A heavily obscured area—such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage—blocks vision entirely.

Devil's sight does let you see even in darkness. But that is separate from the obscuring effects from things such as heavy fog as indicated in the rules text. You can think of it like casting a darkness spell on the other side of a brick wall. Even being able to see into darkness doesn't mean you can see through the wall.