# How can a Mystic circumvent magical fog disrupting line of sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, line-of-sight, mystic

One thing I've found frustrating in recent games is that I, as a Mystic (from [this UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)), need line of sight to many things to be able to use my abilities.

Recently, we've encountered. a lot of fog. I mean a lot.

1. Goblins attack? Foggy.
2. Corrupt guards? Foggy in the guard tower!
3. BBEG? Mysterious fog.

Frankly, it's getting very old. All the other players think it's old.

What are ways that a 5e Mystic can circumvent (cheese) both magical and non-magical fog in a way that my line of sight returns to mostly normal?

For the purposes of this question, assume that the Mystic is human, level 10 or lower, and **cannot multiclass**. Item use is allowed.

**NOTE**: I'm asking for in-game solutions. An answer containing the phrase "Talk to your DM" or similar is not an answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: I see you clearly stated that you don't want advice with DM talking so I will not be answering with a frame challenge but do you then expect that an in-game solution you come up with won't get similarly countered every time in some way?

Comment: Also, this is closely related: [Is there a way to see through smoke as opposed to “darkness”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72780/33707)

Comment: @Sdjz nope! But It's more of a "trick up my sleeve" That I can pull out when the party needs it.

Comment: @Sdjz also: Does blind sight count as line of sight or "A creature you can see"?

Comment: Are you asking about magical or nonmagical fog? Your lead says magical, but the body has both. And FYI, while nice to have, [people don't need to explain downvotes](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-we-require-comments-on-downvotes).

Comment: I've edited the UA link into your post, since you don't seem to have disagreed that that's the version of the mystic you're talking about. Feel free to fix the link if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Gust of Wind

> 2nd level evocation
>
> A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts from you in a direction you choose for the spell's Duration. Each creature that starts its turn in the line must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed 15 feet away from you in a direction following the line.
>
> Any creature in the line must spend 2 feet of Movement for every 1 foot it moves when moving closer to you.
>
> **The gust disperses gas or vapor,** and it extinguishes candles, torches, and similar unprotected flames in the area. It causes protected flames, such as those of lanterns, to dance wildly and has a 50 percent chance to extinguish them.
>
> As a Bonus Action on each of your turns before the spell ends, you can change the direction in which the line blasts from you.

While I don't see a way to cast this on a mystic without multi-classing, there is an item that can do it.

## Wind Fan

> adventuring gear (wondrous item)
>
> Item Rarity: Uncommon
>
> While holding this fan, you can use an action to cast the
> Gust of Wind spell (save DC 13) from it. Once used, the fan shouldn't
> be used again until the next dawn. Each time it is used again before
> then, it has a cumulative 20 percent chance of not working and tearing
> into useless, nonmagical tatters.

The spell doesn't distinguish between magical and nonmagical gas or vapor, but it will likely still depend on DM ruling. The spell **Fog cloud** specifically says

> You create a 20-foot-radius Sphere of fog centered on a point within range. The Sphere spreads around corners, and its area is heavily obscured. **It lasts for the Duration or until a wind of moderate or greater speed (at least 10 miles per hour) disperses it.**

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the [UA Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) to get an idea of what options are open to the PC, and remember that multiclassing isn't an option for this PC per the text in the question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast edited my answer to include the description of a wind fan, to more emphasize that these spells will likely have to come from an item, which is an allowed option.

Comment: Cool, nice improvement. :)  (pun intended)